# Relatively modify a property's value

Tags: css, properties, modifier

I would like to decrease a certain margin's size by 25% in certain cases. I could do this by looking at it's base value and manually entering 75% of the value. However, the margin's base size varies according to client screen resolution.

Therefore I would like to decrease the *already defined* margin value by 25%.
If one were to be doing an analogous thing in Python programming, the equivalent would thus be:

```
margin = some_base_value
...
margin = 0.75*margin
```

Can I do this in CSS, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use Sass or LESS ,
so you can use variables.

Example: (Sass (SCSS))

```
$margin: 10px;

#element {
    margin: $margin*.75;
}
```

.. if you don't want to use any css preprocessor, you can use [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) with [calc function](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp).